# Save and close a word document by giving a name in R

Tags: r, ms-word, desctools

I am trying to use two libraries (`DescsTool`, `R2wd`) in order to get descriptive analysis of a dataset saved in a folder for exploration later. These are the steps I am trying

```
library(DescTools)
library(R2wd)
data(iris)

i <- ls()    
wrd <- GetNewWrd(header=TRUE)
wdGet()
Desc(get(i), plotit=TRUE, wrd=wrd)

wdSave(Name="temp.doc", wdapp=.R2wd)
wdQuit()
```

Although word is capturing output as supposed to be, I cannot save the word file giving a name (e.g.: temp.doc). Can someone shed some light here?

Comment: Hi guys, it seems the syntax is working. Only thing is it saves in a default folder (My Documents) and I am able to change it using `Z:\\Project\\temp.doc`.

Comment: `Desc(get(i), plotit=TRUE, wrd=wrd)` might not work. If so, remove `plotit` arg and it should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
library(DescTools)
wrd <- GetNewWrd()
Desc(iris, wrd=wrd)

wrd[["ActiveDocument"]]$SaveAs2(FileName="Describe iris.docx")
wrd$Quit()
```